# matlab noninteger step indexing

Tags: matlab

So, I have a vector:

```
k = 1:100;
```

And I want to take 19 elements from it, which are roughly equally-spaced. So I write this:

```
m = k(1:(99/18):end);
```

This works great, except for a tiny problem:

```
Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index

m =

     1     7    12    18    23    29    34    40    45    51    56    62    67    73    78    84    89    95   100
```

Now, I understand why this comes up, but I'd like to get rid of that warning. Is there a "right" way to do this without a warning?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "roughly equally spaced"?

Comment: Well, here, since I want 19 elements, I want 1:5.5:end to get those elements from the array. For example, suppose I had some function that I wanted to downsample by a noninteger factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
floor(linspace(1,100,19))
```

Comment: Well, in real life, K isn't just a linear vector. However, I suppose `m = k(floor(linspace(1, numel(k), 19))` is pretty good.